# Arrays, having trouble understanding how to set it up

Tags: java, arrays

Working with arrays, the question asks:

1. Write a java program that declares an array alpha to 50 elements of type double.
2. Initialize the array so that the first 25 numbers are equal to the square of the index variable
3. And the last 25 elements are equal to 3 times the index variable.
4. Output the array so that 10 elements per line are printed.

I only have a few lines of code, I have no idea exactly what i should be doing.

```
    public class ch9_problem1{
        public static void main(String[] args){
            double[] alpha = new double[50];
            for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++){
                System.out.print(alpha[x] + "\n");
            }       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Trouble with what ? You should read a tutorial about arrays, that will help you to understand how it works. Then you'll solve easily this problem. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: Maybe you should ask your teacher.

Comment: Maybe you need to set `alpha[x]` to something inside your loop.  You can expect the values to be all null when the array is first created.

Comment: I edited your question to make the steps clearer.  Code each step separately.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, you should continue experimenting as you are.

Your loop is correct in iterating over the first 25 elements, and you clearly understand how to access elements in the array as shown here.

```
alpha[x]
```

From here, you should be able to use some simple math and your loop counter x (your index variable) to set each element (alpha[x]).

For the second half, you're simply starting your loop from 25 instead of 0!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to just give you the answer since this is clearly for a class, but I added in a bit of pseudocode to help you out. Hopefully this doesn't give away too much.

```
public class ch9_problem1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // STEP 1 - You got this right!
        double[] alpha = new double[50];

        // STEP 2 - SOLVE:
        // for int i - make a loop that goes through the first half of the array {
        //    alpha[i] = i * i;
        // }

        // STEP 3 - SOLVE:
        // for int i - make a loop that goes through the second half of the array {
        //    alpha[i] = 3 * i;
        // }

            // I changed the loop to go until we're at the last element of the array
        for(int x = 0; x < alpha.length-1; x++)
        {

            System.out.print(alpha[x]);
            // STEP 4 - SOLVE:
            // If this element's position is a multiple of 10 
            //   System.out.print("\n");
            // HINT: Use a remainder (modulo) operator
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    double[] alpha = new double[50];

    for(int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        if (x<25) alpha[x] = x*x;
        if (x>=25) alpha[x] = x*x*x;

        System.out.print(alpha[x]);

        if (x%10 == 0)  System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be 3*x instead of x*x*x.  Otherwise correct, but not helpful to the OP's learning.

Comment: You should not give the entire solution away so freely. This is clearly for a class and he should have to work for the answer in order to learn.

Answer (score 0):

> ...that declares an array alpha to 50 elements of type double.

This is correct.

```
double[] alpha = new double[50];
```

> Initialize the array so that the first 25 numbers are equal to the square of the index variable, and the last 25 elements are equal to 3 times the index variable.

This is partly done with your loop

```
for(int x = 0; x < 25; x++)
```

`x` is your index variable, which will have another value for each iteration. It starts by 0 and ends by 24 (which is < 25).

Now you have to use x as your index and assign your values, for the first 25 with the square of the index, like

```
alpha[x] = x*x;
```

The other 25 with the equal to 3 times the index, so you should assign the next 25 with `x*3`.

After that you have to do a loop of 10 in a loop of 5 to output 10 entries at a time and for all your entries, which are 50.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array of type double with a size of 50 (you did that.)
- Populate the first 25 elements so they have a value of  `index*index`.  This will require a loop of twenty five iterations.
- Populate the last 25 elements so they have a value of `3*index`.  This will require a loop of twenty five iterations. (hint: It's possible to incorporate this with the previous loop, giving a single loop of 25 iterations.)
- Loop over the contents of the array and print 10 elements 5 times.